# run a script on windows without having to explicitely indicate the interpreter (like in Linux)

Tags: windows, executable, createprocess, shebang, external-script

I am developing a portable building framework. On Linux, the framework works perfectly. However on Windows, the framework cannot execute scripts: Windows allows running `*.exe` and `*.com` only.

**Question:** Is there an executable (`*.exe` or `*.com`) that:

1. reads a file having same filename except `.exe` extension (`bar.py.exe` -> `bar.py`)
2. searches this file on the same directory (`C:\dir\bar.py.exe` -> `C:\dir\bar.py`)
3. parses the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) of the file (`bar.py` -> `#!/usr/bin/python`)
4. executes the interpreter (`python`)
5. passes the name of the script (`C:\dir\bar.py` or `/c/dir/bar.py` or `/cygdrive/c/dir/bar.py`)
6. also passes its command-line parameters

I do not know how to find a such project...

Below more details to understand better my issue.

---

**Details:**

My building framework is based on [Ant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ant):

```
<target name="repo.init">
  <exec executable="repo" dir="${dir}">
    <arg value="init"   />
    <arg value="-u"     />
    <arg value="${url}" />
  </exec>
</target>
```

On Windows, Ant (java) cannot find executable [`repo`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repo_%28script%29).

I do not want to mess up the Ant scripts just because of Windows:

```
<target name="repo.init">
  <exec executable="python" dir="${dir}">
    <arg value="repo"   />
    <arg value="init"   />
    <arg value="-u"     />
    <arg value="${url}" />
  </exec>
</target>
```

Therefore I attempted a [batch script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) running the python script:

```
$ dir
2013-09-23  10:30       738  repo
2013-09-23  10:31        23  repo.bat
$ type repo.bat
python %~dp0/repo %*
```

But same error! My colleague specifies [`cmd`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_Prompt) when he runs batch file from Ant :(

```
<target name="repo.init">
  <exec executable="cmd" dir="${dir}">
    <arg value="/c"      />
    <arg value="repo.bat"/>
    <arg value="init"    />
    <arg value="-u"      />
    <arg value="${url}"  />
  </exec>
</target>
```

---

As my issue is common on various projects mixing external scripts, I am wondering if an elegant solution has already been implemented...

We could use an executable having same name as the script. When this executable is run, it reads the script located on the same directory, parse the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) and execute this script using the specified interpreter.

**Demo:**

```
C:\dir> dir
 Volume in drive C is OSDisk
 Volume Serial Number is 56A4-E980

 Directory of C:\dir

23/09/2013  17:19    <DIR>          .
23/09/2013  17:19    <DIR>          ..
23/09/2013  17:15            23 535 repo
23/09/2013  17:25            89 521 repo.exe
           2 File(s)        113 056 bytes
           2 Dir(s)  122 670 903 296 bytes free

C:\dir> head -1 repo
Unknown option: 1
[...]
C:\dir> powershell -command "& {get-content repo -totalcount 1}"  
#!/usr/bin/env python

C:\dir> repo.exe arg1 arg2
[... --> execute "python C:\dir\repo arg1 arg2" ...]
```

This is easy to implement (for instance using [`CreateProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx)). But I would prefer to reuse a similar tool already developed.

**I am open to any other ideas solving this issue...**

Answer (score 1):

I finally found, I post here my solution to be useful for others ;)

**There are two projects on GitHub:**

- **[snaury/script-runner](https://github.com/snaury/script-runner)** --> `[script].exe` looks for files named `[script].ext` (where `.ext` is defined at compile time like `.rb`, `.pl`, `.tcl` or empty) and for every existing `[script].ext` file, `script-runner` executes the script using the corresponding interpreter (defined at compile time like `ruby.exe`, `perl.exe`, `tclsh.exe`, `tclkitsh.exe`). I have [forked it](https://github.com/olibre/script-runner) and extended to python.
- **[CBWhiz/RunHiddenCmd](https://github.com/CBWhiz/RunHiddenCmd)**  --> `[targetfilename].exe` passes its command line parameters to local file having same filename (`[targetfilename]`, `[targetfilename].cmd`, or `[targetfilename].bat`). `RunHiddenCmd` uses `cmd.exe` for `.cmd` or `.bat`.

**My fork:**

- **[olibre/script-runner](https://github.com/olibre/script-runner)** --> forked the first one (from [Alexey Borzenkov](https://github.com/snaury)) + added support for Python :-)

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, I would recommend the [Python Launcher](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher) (`py.exe` which is optionally installed during the Python setup). It does the job you are asking for.

When developing multi-platform applications using a shebang for distributed scripts is still recommended. `setuptools` changes the shebang for scripts mentioned in the `scripts` argument of `setuptools.setup()` in `setup.py` to a value suitable for the target platform: https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-scripts